# How does a exec'ed shell know your cwd?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

If you `cd` to some directory other than `$HOME` and run `exec bash`, the new bash starts in the working directory of the previous shell.

How does the new bash know what the previous working directory was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It inherits its working directory just like every process inherits its parent's working directory.

How do you think the `pwd` program works? It just gets its own working directory with the `getcwd` system call, which it inherited from its parent.

Answer (score 3):

A process task structure has a current working directory that is inherited. On Linux, you can see it like this:

```
ls -l /proc/self/cwd
```

When you create a new shell, it inherits the parent process' current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

The *working directory* is a property provided by the operating system and is attributed to a process whether they want it or not.

A process (child) spawned by another process (parent) receives the spawning process' working directory without any intervention on its part.

Aside from a process using the working directory as part of its design, it can also be used by the OS for things such as determining the location of core dumps when the process crashes.